# detecting circular reference

Tags: java, recursion

So in an interview, I was actually asked a simple question that goes like this, say that I have a nested JSON response, [a, b, c ,d [a, [b, [d, e], g], h]. I am asked to implement a class that basically can handle to store this data and a print method to do so, so here's what I have:

```
public class JSONode
{
   private String str;
   private JSONode nodes;

   public JSONode (String a, ArrayList<String> n)
   {
        str = a;
        nodes = n;
   }
}

public class JSONResp
{
  private ArrayList<JSONode> arr;

  public JSONResp ()
  {
    arr = new ArrayList<JSONode>();
  }

  public boolean checkCircular(JSONode temp)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr.get(i).nodes == temp)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void add (JSONode nd)
  {
    if (!checkCircular(nd))
    arr.add(nd);
  }

  public void recurseJSONode(JSONode)
  {
      if (!JSONode.node)
           System.out.print(JSONode.str);
      else {
          System.out.print(JSONode.str);
          recurseJSONode(JSONode.node);
      }
  }

  public void print()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
       recurseJSONode(arr.get(i));
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
      JSONResp x = new JSONResp();
      x.add(new JSONode("a", null);
      x.add(new JSONode("b", null);
  }

}
```

Now he said that there will circular references issues when I print, in other words I have list A = [a, b, c, D] and D = [q, t, y, A]. So he said I'd have to prevent from adding D by using the checkCircular above. I made an attempt. Also just a node I know my recurseJSONode isn't correct and so does the print, so looking for a suggestion to fix that as well.. I am just curious to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it should be like

```
public class JSONode
{
   private String str;
   private ArrayList<JSONode> nodes;

   public JSONode (String a, ArrayList<JSONode> n)
   {
        str = a;
        nodes = n;
   }
}
```

You have to check recursivly, if the given node is part of the parent node and the parent of the parent and so on...

So more like

```
public static boolean checkCircular(JSONode temp)
  {
    if(temp == null){
       return false;
    }

    ArrayList<JSONode> pNodes = temp.getChildrens();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
    {
        if (pNodes.get(i).getString().equals(temp.getString()))
            return true;
        if(checkCircular(temp))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: why are you making it so that it checks for a JSNode and ArrayList?

Comment: This is a basic recursive search algorithm. A Class nows his parents or childrens. For every class you have to check the referenced classes, whether it matches your search criterion. if not, you have to check the referenced classes of the referenced class. At the beginning of the algorithm you have to define a stop criterion, for stopping the recursive calls. Just google and you find some easy recursive examples

Comment: if you can give an example on how this would be called, it would be clear..as in my case I am only passing a JSONode to the checkCircular, however you have ArrayList<JSONode> there as well, I am just confused on what is this

Comment: when you do pNodes.get(i).getString() it gives you the reference I assume of the JSONNode and you're comparing if the references are the same?

Answer (score 5):

The reason your circular check isn't right is that you only look for an existing duplicate of JSONode under the one node you're trying to add it to. But A might be under B and B is under A, so each is unique within its parent's list.

Re: using a stack for tracking activity in a recursive function:

```
Set<SomeNodeType> stack = new HashSet<SomeNodeType>();
someRecursiveThing(rootNode, stack);
```

And then inside someRecursiveThing:

```
void someRecursiveThing(SomeNodeType under, Set<SomeNodeType> stack) {

    if (!stack.add(under)) {
        return;

    // continue happily, e.g. call self with child node,
    // passing down the stack

    SomeNodeType child = ...
    someRecursiveThing(child, stack)

    // finish by removing 'under' from the stack:
    stack.remove(under);
}
```

The advantage of `HashSet` is that `add` and `remove` typically run in constant time - the size of the tree is irrelevant.

For comparison:

Markus Lausberg's answer suggests doing a complete recursive search of the whole tree, which would be O(N) where N is the number of nodes in the tree, and as you are doing that check for every node it ends up being O(N^2). A tree of 10 nodes will do 100 node comparisons; a tree of 1000 nodes will do 1000,0000 node comparisons.

In kan's answer the check involves searching the parent chain, which will depend on the depth of the tree. For a perfectly lopsided tree (worst case) the depth will be the same as the number of nodes, giving O(N^2) again. For a balanced tree the depth will be ~log N, not much better (remember, the check has to be done for every node).

The effect of these differences depends on the comparison operation used to determine if two nodes are the same. If it is just a pointer comparison (i.e. you only care if they're the same object) and the tree is never very large, the overhead of `HashSet` may have a negative impact. Whereas if you need to compare two nodes in a more complex way, so each comparison is expensive, and the tree is large, then the optimised lookup of `HashSet` will become beneficial.

Comment: I have a meeting just starting... will answer later if you haven't already had suggestions by then.

Comment: As a hint: as you recurse down the tree, keep a stack of nodes on the current "path". If the next node you try to visit is already on the stack, don't bother to visit it.

Comment: The ideal collection for the stack is HashSet, as you can check very quickly if a node is in the set or not.

Comment: can you give me some code? I like your answer of using a stack as we go down the tree